# Flutter: What changes in Github Workflow are needed after adding signingConfigs to build.gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, github, workflow, publish

For my flutter app i had a GitHub workflow to create the release apk on every commit and it was working perfectly:

```yaml
on: push
name: Build VolTrac APK
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        distribution: 'zulu'
        java-version: '11'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        flutter-version: '2.10.4'
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
    - name: Create a Release APK
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: release-apk
        path: build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

But now as I need to publish the app in Play Store i did the following changes to build gradle:

```dart
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

I have kept the sensitive information in a key.properties file that obviously I don't want to upload to GitHub but without it the workflow won't run so I need the alternative.
[The error in workflow is unable to find key.properties file as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPyRL.png)

This causes the app to not build in my workflow, question is **how do I change my GitHub workflow in such a way that my app gets build** without publicly uploading key.properties file or the .jks file.

I already searched about GitHub secrets but i didn't understand how would it help.

Lastly, the key.properties file looks like:

```
storePassword=***
keyPassword=***
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/myname/key.jks
```

**EDIT**

1. So I created a private repository and added key.properties and .jks file with correct path to it. Although I didn't fully understand how we will access it.
2. In the public repo where all the code and the workflow to build the app is present, I added 4 secret variables and changed workflow.yaml to this:

```yaml
on: push
name: Build VolTrac APK
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
      RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD }}
      RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS }}
      RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH }}   
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        distribution: 'zulu'
        java-version: '11'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        flutter-version: '2.10.4'
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
    - name: Create a Release APK
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: release-apk
        path: build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

The build gradle has been changed to:

```dart
signingConfigs { 
    release { 
        keyAlias ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS }} 
        keyPassword ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }} 
        storeFile file(${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH }}) 
        storePassword ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD }} 
    } 
}
```

Now two things,

- I didn't understand how to use those 4 secret variables here and how to access the .jks file which is inside a private repo.
- I want the app to build locally as well so I don't want to change it in a way that will require me to change it again if I want to locally run `"flutter build apk --split-per-abi"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment on GitHub Actions. Solution can be:

1. create private repository and place sign key to them;
2. create secrets with sign information and add it to your build config;
3. read sign information in `build.gradle` from environment.

More about secrets [here](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md).

Your build setup can be similar to my:

```yaml
name: Create Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ release ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH }}
      RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
      RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS }}
      RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Checkout metadata
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: hash-checker/metadata
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          path: './metadata'

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11

      - name: Build Release Bundle
        run: ./gradlew bundleRelease --stacktrace

      - name: Build Release APK
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace

      - name: Put version name to ENV
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: 'true'
        run: echo ::set-env name=RELEASE_NAME::$(echo "3.6.9")

      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}
          release_name: ${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false

      - name: Upload Release Bundle with Google Play services
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: 'app/build/outputs/bundle/googlePlayRelease/hash-checker_release.aab'
          asset_name: hash-checker_google-play_${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}.aab
          asset_content_type: application/zip

      - name: Upload Release Bundle without Google Play services
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: 'app/build/outputs/bundle/thirdPartyStoresRelease/hash-checker_release.aab'
          asset_name: hash-checker_no-google-play_${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}.aab
          asset_content_type: application/zip

      - name: Upload Release APK with Google Play services
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: 'app/build/outputs/apk/googlePlay/release/hash-checker_release.apk'
          asset_name: hash-checker_google-play_${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}.apk
          asset_content_type: application/zip

      - name: Upload Release APK without Google Play services
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: 'app/build/outputs/apk/thirdPartyStores/release/hash-checker_release.apk'
          asset_name: hash-checker_no-google-play_${{ env.RELEASE_NAME }}.apk
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```

Comment: I think I have somewhat understood, but if I changed build.gradle to read sign information from environment of GitHub secrets, it the same code won't build in my local unless I change it back to read from keystore.properties?

Comment: Also how do I access the jks file

Comment: I edited my question with some of your suggestions, kindly review

Comment: You need to add reading from environment in your `build.gradle` because you can place GitHub Secrets in env on GitHub (and when your build are executing on it, env is available with secrets).

Comment: Still I didn't understand how will it access the .jks file.. I can surely give the path/to/file.jks as secret, but not the file itself can be uploaded as secret

Comment: You can create a private repository and get a file from this repository. Second step in my example is a checkouting repository with key.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I tried it again today but "A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'." Also I am not sure how to add gihtub secrets to build.gradle , I simply did: signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS }}
        keyPassword ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
        storeFile file(${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH }})
        storePassword ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD }}
    }
}

Comment: I also couldn't find a suitable tutorial for if the app gets signingconfigs what changes to make in the GitHub workflow so it builds both locally and on deployment, that would have been helpful

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/hash-checker/hash-checker and see solution in this repo.